# How do I use a HTML input box to set a JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write a simple one page calculator script with user input. With my semi-lack of JS knowledge I keep running into issues. I feel like what I am doing should work and is correct but I am obviously missing something here.

I would like my HTML input box's to set the variables for my JS function. I just can not figure out what I am doing wrong here.

If I could have a nudge in the right direction I would be more than thankful.

```html
<body>
   <input type="text" id="price"=>Price</input>
   <br>
   <input type="text" id="value"=>Value</input>
   <br>
   <button onclick="sub()">Submit</button>
</body>
<script>      
   function sub() {
           
   var value = document.getElementById("value").value;
   var price = document.getElementById("price").value;
           
   var keep = value * 0.7
   var sell = keep * 0.7
   var profit = sell / 1000 * 6 - price
   var keeprate = price / keep * 1000
   var earned = profit + price
   
   
   
   document.write("Keeping: R$ ");
   document.write(keep);
   document.write("<br>");
   document.write("1k Buy Rate: $");
   document.write(keeprate);
   document.write("<br>");
   document.write("<br>");
   document.write("Selling: R$ ");
   document.write(sell);
   document.write("<br>");
   document.write("1k Buy Rate: ");
   document.write("$6.00");
   document.write("<br>");
   document.write("<br>");
   document.write("Total Cost $");
   document.write(price)
   document.write("<br>");
   document.write("Total Return $");
   document.write(earned)
   document.write("<br>");
   document.write("Net: $");
   document.write(profit);
   }
</script>
```

Comment: document.getElementById("value").value = 'something'

Comment: document.write will obliterate your existing document. This is not wise.

Comment: This is temporary. I appreciate the heads up. I am formatting it into HTML

Comment: There is no such thing as `</input>` and you've got an extra `=` after your `id`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your main issue is your function declaration. You have no opening and closing bracket for `function sub()`

Add an opening and closing bracket to properly declare your function.

```
function sub() {

    code

}
```